# When exactly OOM_KILLER will be invoked

Tags: linux, out-of-memory

I currently have the situation where OOM_KILLER is invoked while (i think) there is some RAM not used. I know that is will happen when "there is no more memory in the system", but then what is the definition of that? How that relates to Swap?.

It looks like it is happening when I hit ~64GB of virtual memory which is (coincidence) the same ammount of RAM beeing installed on the system. I end up with situation like this:

```
[Fri Jan 11 02:11:48 2019] Killed process 28863 (java) total-vm:65134452kB, anon-rss:18437996kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
```

If the anon-rss is actual RAM used - then there is over 40GB left to be used, but still OOMK istrigered. 
Why is that? Is 64GB some sort of magic barier? Or is it because vmem exceeded physical ram size?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How does the OOM killer decide which process to kill first?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/153585)

Comment: How much RAM is used in the system as a whole? 18G is the resident size (backed by anonymous pages) of the single `java` process which is being killed.

Comment: I have no clue I just can't read dmesg outpu, but check this as it has more complete dmesg log - https://serverfault.com/questions/948631/why-total-vm-is-is-different-than-show-in-table?noredirect=1#comment1232767_948631